# SearchView filter is working as intented, but retrieves old item position on RecyclerView in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I've been searching the past few days for a solution to my issue, but all other similar issues seem to have a problem with an `onClickListener` or their solution isn't intended for the issue at hand. It seems like the `onClickListeners` I use in my project are working as intended, only the `SearchView` is not.

My starting list consists of some items and their ingredients/materials, and everything is working as intented. When filtered with the `SearchView`, the new filtered list is showing correct item names but wrong ingredients. Literally the old position before the filtering and I can't seem to debug where the problem is coming from.

`MainAdapter.java`

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<Item> mItemCard;
    private List<Item> mItemCardFull; //Needed for the getFilter() method

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        // region Variables (Item Name, Icon, Expand Layout & Expand button)
        ImageView mItemIcon;
        TextView mItemName;
        ImageButton mExpandButton;
        // etc...

        // region Variables (Ingredients' Icons, Names & Amount)
        ImageView mIngredient_1_Icon;
        TextView mIngredient_1_Name;
        TextView mIngredient_1_amountTV;
        float mIngredient_1_amount;
        // etc...

        // region misc Variables
        boolean _isFirstTime = true; // Used in initialization & crafting method switch
        EditText editFactoryAmount;
        ImageView factoryAmountIcon;
        Button factoryAmountButton;
        // etc...


        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mItemIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon);
            mItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            mIngredient_1_Icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_1_icon);
            mIngredient_1_Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_1_name);
            mIngredient_1_amountTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_1_amount);
        // etc...
        }
    }

    public MainAdapter(List<Item> itemCard) {
        this.mItemCard = itemCard;
        this.mItemCardFull = new ArrayList<>(itemCard);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Item currentItem = mItemCard.get(position);

        final float craftingTime = currentItem.getCraftingTime();
        final float outputAmount = currentItem.getOutputAmount();

        holder.mItemIcon.setImageResource(currentItem.getItemIcon());
        holder.mItemName.setText(currentItem.getItemName());
        holder.mExpandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean show = toggleLayout(!currentItem.isExpanded(), view, holder.mExpandedLayout);
                currentItem.setExpanded(show);
            }
        });

        // region Textwatchers
        // region Editor Listeners
        /* Editor Listener: When actionDone is clicked on the soft keyboard, clear focus from editText */

        // other random methods included in the project which arent relevant
        // ......
    }

    /* Expands or collapses depending on item state */
    private boolean toggleLayout(boolean isExpanded, View v, ConstraintLayout expandedLayout) {
        Animations.toggleArrow(v, isExpanded);
        if (isExpanded) {
            Animations.expand(expandedLayout);
        } else {
            Animations.collapse(expandedLayout);
        }
        return isExpanded;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemCard.size();
    }

    /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Search Filter Setup ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
    /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return itemFilter;
    }

    private Filter itemFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(mItemCardFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (Item item : mItemCardFull) {
                    if (item.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mItemCard.clear();
            mItemCard.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

`IntermediatesFragment.java`

```
public class IntermediatesFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MainAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


    public IntermediatesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View thisFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mRecyclerView = thisFragment.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());


        createItemList();
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return thisFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void createItemList() {
        ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        // region Intermediates Items
        // etc items ...

        mAdapter = new MainAdapter(itemList);
    }
}
```

The problem seems to go away if I include "`setIsRecyclable(false)`" in the `Viewholder`, but then the performance is awful on low-end phones and the cards are destroyed/resetted when they exit the view which is not a desirable behaviour.

Edit with full `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Item currentItem = mItemCard.get(position);

        final float craftingTime = currentItem.getCraftingTime();
        final float outputAmount = currentItem.getOutputAmount();

        holder.mItemIcon.setImageResource(currentItem.getItemIcon());
        holder.mItemName.setText(currentItem.getItemName());
        holder.mExpandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean show = toggleLayout(!currentItem.isExpanded(), view, holder.mExpandedLayout);
                currentItem.setExpanded(show);
            }
        });

        // region Ingredients' Icons, Names & Amounts
        holder.mIngredient_1_Icon.setImageResource(currentItem.getIngredientIcon_1());
        holder.mIngredient_2_Icon.setImageResource(currentItem.getIngredientIcon_2());
        holder.mIngredient_3_Icon.setImageResource(currentItem.getIngredientIcon_3());
        holder.mIngredient_4_Icon.setImageResource(currentItem.getIngredientIcon_4());
        holder.mIngredient_5_Icon.setImageResource(currentItem.getIngredientIcon_5());
        holder.mIngredient_6_Icon.setImageResource(currentItem.getIngredientIcon_6());

        holder.mIngredient_1_Name.setText(currentItem.getIngredientName_1());
        holder.mIngredient_2_Name.setText(currentItem.getIngredientName_2());
        holder.mIngredient_3_Name.setText(currentItem.getIngredientName_3());
        holder.mIngredient_4_Name.setText(currentItem.getIngredientName_4());
        holder.mIngredient_5_Name.setText(currentItem.getIngredientName_5());
        holder.mIngredient_6_Name.setText(currentItem.getIngredientName_6());

        holder.mIngredient_1_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getIngredientAmount_1()));
        holder.mIngredient_2_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getIngredientAmount_2()));
        holder.mIngredient_3_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getIngredientAmount_3()));
        holder.mIngredient_4_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getIngredientAmount_4()));
        holder.mIngredient_5_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getIngredientAmount_5()));
        holder.mIngredient_6_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getIngredientAmount_6()));


        if (currentItem.getIngredientName_1() == R.string.item_null) {
            holder.mIngredient_1_Icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mIngredient_1_Name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mIngredient_1_amountTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);\

        // if statements continue for the rest of the 5 ingredients
        // endregion Ingredients' Icons, Names & Amounts

        holder.factoryAmountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.button_f++;
                float factoryAmount = Float.parseFloat(holder.editFactoryAmount.getText().toString());
                float outputSpeed = Float.parseFloat((holder.editItemOutput.getText().toString()));
                if (currentItem.getCraftingMethod().equals("Assembler")) {
                    switch (holder.button_f) {
                        case 0:
                            holder.factoryAmountIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pf_assembling_machine_1);
                            holder.craftingSpeed = 0.50f;
                            if (holder.editItemOutput.isFocused()) {
                                holder.factoryAmount = (outputSpeed * craftingTime) / ((outputAmount * holder.craftingSpeed) * (1 + (holder.speedModuleAmount * holder.speed)) * (1 + (holder.prodModuleAmount * holder.productivity)));
                                holder.editFactoryAmount.setText(String.valueOf(holder.factoryAmount));
                                // region Edit Ingredients' Amount
                                holder.factoryAmount = Float.parseFloat(holder.editFactoryAmount.getText().toString());
                                holder.mIngredient_1_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_1()) / craftingTime;
                                holder.mIngredient_1_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_1_amount));

                                holder.mIngredient_2_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_2()) / craftingTime;
                                holder.mIngredient_2_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_2_amount));

                                holder.mIngredient_3_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_3()) / craftingTime;
                                holder.mIngredient_3_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_3_amount));

                                holder.mIngredient_4_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_4()) / craftingTime;
                                holder.mIngredient_4_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_4_amount));

                                holder.mIngredient_5_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_5()) / craftingTime;
                                holder.mIngredient_5_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_5_amount));

                                holder.mIngredient_6_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_6()) / craftingTime;
                                holder.mIngredient_6_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_6_amount));


            // it goes on in the same pattern depending on other circumstances


        /*~~~~~~~~~~~~ Initialization & Crafting Method Switch ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
        if (holder.editFactoryAmount.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !holder.editFactoryAmount.isFocused()) {
            holder.editFactoryAmount.setText(String.valueOf(1.0f));
            holder.outputSpeed = ((Float.parseFloat(holder.editFactoryAmount.getText().toString()) * holder.craftingSpeed) * (1 + (holder.speedModuleAmount * holder.speed))) / craftingTime * (1 + (holder.prodModuleAmount * holder.productivity)) * outputAmount;
            holder.editItemOutput.setText(String.valueOf(holder.outputSpeed));
        }

        float factoryAmount = Float.parseFloat(holder.editFactoryAmount.getText().toString());
        switch (currentItem.getCraftingMethod()) {
            case "Assembler":
                // If it's the first time the app starts, set default crafting speed, else keep as it is.
                if (holder._isFirstTime) {
                    holder.craftingSpeed = 0.50f;
                    holder._isFirstTime = false;
                }
                if (holder.craftingSpeed == 0.50f) {
                    holder.factoryAmountIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pf_assembling_machine_1);
                    holder.button_f = 0;
                } else if (holder.craftingSpeed == 0.75f) {
                    holder.factoryAmountIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pf_assembling_machine_2);
                    holder.button_f = 1;
                } else {
                    holder.factoryAmountIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pf_assembling_machine_3);
                }
                holder.outputSpeed = ((factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed) * (1 + (holder.speedModuleAmount * holder.speed))) / craftingTime * (1 + (holder.prodModuleAmount * holder.productivity)) * outputAmount;
                holder.editItemOutput.setText(String.valueOf(holder.outputSpeed));
                // region Edit Ingredients' Amount
                holder.factoryAmount = Float.parseFloat(holder.editFactoryAmount.getText().toString());
                holder.mIngredient_1_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_1()) / craftingTime;
                holder.mIngredient_1_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_1_amount));

                holder.mIngredient_2_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_2()) / craftingTime;
                holder.mIngredient_2_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_2_amount));

                holder.mIngredient_3_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_3()) / craftingTime;
                holder.mIngredient_3_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_3_amount));

                holder.mIngredient_4_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_4()) / craftingTime;
                holder.mIngredient_4_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_4_amount));

                holder.mIngredient_5_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_5()) / craftingTime;
                holder.mIngredient_5_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_5_amount));

                holder.mIngredient_6_amount = (holder.factoryAmount * holder.craftingSpeed * currentItem.getIngredientAmount_6()) / craftingTime;
                holder.mIngredient_6_amountTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.mIngredient_6_amount));
                // endregion Edit Ingredients' Amount
                break;
            case "Smelter":
            // thing happening here and etc for all the other cases
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the *full* `onBindViewHolder`?  Specifically how you set up the item name and ingredients.  The bug is very likely there.

Comment: Not sure of the etiquette of SO, should I edit the full onBind on my original question or on paste in? Due to circumstances that particular part of the code is large.

Comment: Generally everything needed to answer should be in the question.  I could speculate about which parts, but I'm pretty sure based on your description that the bug isn't in what's there now.

Comment: I edited the `onBindViewHolder`, due to character limit I removed all the redundant repetitive patterns, but the whole gist is still there.

Comment: Cool, I took a crack at it.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell *exactly* what's wrong here without the full picture, but...

You're holding a lot of state in your ViewHolder, like whether it's the first time, the ingredient amounts, etc.  You really want to *only* hold `View`s there, because they can be swapped unpredictably between items.  That's why it works when you tell it they're not recyclable - it doesn't do that any more.

You're also setting things to GONE, but not VISIBLE if they should be shown.  This is a problem for recycling:

```
holder.mIngredient_1_Icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Your button onClick listener is modifying state in the holder - that's bad, because the holders will get swapped between items, and maybe rebound.  You really want allllll this state in your `Item` class.  Once you do that, and your RecyclerView becomes a one-way transformation from `Item`s to an onBindViewHolder that sets up everything, it'll be a lot easier to reason about.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think you are right about not setting them to VISIBLE for recycle. You must  be very close. I would need to create an interface to pass all the state into my `Item` class?

Comment: Thanks. After some thought I added an `else { holder.mIngredient_1_Icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and it worked. Although you didn't immediately solved the question, your answer was what I needed to figure out what was wrong, which in hind sight it was very obvious. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls try this

```
class SectionRecyclerViewAdapter(
    var sectionModelArrayList: ArrayList<SectionModel>,
    val context: Activity
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private val mSectionList: List<SectionModel>? = sectionModelArrayList

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.section_custom_row_layout, viewGroup, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val sectionModel = sectionModelArrayList[position]
        holder.tvStations.text = sectionModel.stations
        holder.ivLogo.setImageDrawable(sectionModel.logo)
        holder.ivArrow.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_arrow_dark)
        holder.view.setOnClickListener {
            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    val intent = Intent(context, AllUserActivity::class.java)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                    context.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left)
                }
                1 -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Nothing to Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }


            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return sectionModelArrayList.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val ivLogo: ImageView
        val tvStations: TextView
        val ivArrow: ImageView
        val view: View


        init {
            ivLogo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo)
            tvStations = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStations)
            ivArrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrow)
            view = itemView
        }
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            protected override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): FilterResults {
                val charString = charSequence.toString()
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    sectionModelArrayList = mSectionList as ArrayList<SectionModel>
                } else {
                    var filteredList = ArrayList<SectionModel>()
                    if (mSectionList != null) {
                        for (row in mSectionList) {

                            // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                            // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                            if (row.stations.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                                filteredList.add(row)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    sectionModelArrayList = filteredList
                }

                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = sectionModelArrayList
                return filterResults
            }

            override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence, filterResults: FilterResults) {
                sectionModelArrayList = filterResults.values as ArrayList<SectionModel>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried my hardest to adapt the presented code to mine, but I can't seem to make it work and the Kotlin is not making it easy either.

Answer (score 0):

Passing filtered list to adapter will resolved the issue.

Comment: the filter is in the adapter and it modifies the list there, what do you mean?

Comment: when it modifies the list then after you need to notify adapter that data set has been changed. Simply do notifyDataSetChanged after you updated your list with the filtered list.

Comment: Tell me if the problem is still there. I will then do code myself and will send it to you.